# Are we going to get the shiny new profile pages as on Stack Overflow and some other sites

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I don't know how things work at Stack Exchange central, some of the sites look like they only differ in terms of CSS, but some of the Stack Exchange sites, Stack Overflow, Database Admin and Spanish Language being the ones I am aware of, have a new, enhanced profile page. Are we going to get it on GIS?

One nice feature, is the impact box, which gives you an idea of how many people you might have helped in some way.

Comment: The [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com) site was updated today. I think it won't take too long for GIS being updated too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**: the [new site design is now live for GIS](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/site-design-updates-are-live).

---

I like the new profile pages and the impact box too.

We are on the list but as mentioned at

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/

it needs a CSS update and we are in the half of sites that are awaiting theirs:

[List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)

In the meantime there is another tool (only accessible to 10K+ users) that we are missing out on related to site-specific close reasons for which an upvote [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257453) could be helpful.

Comment: Oh, great. I was correct that it is mostly CSS then.