# Inappropriate use of Title Case in question stats (Asked / Viewed / Active)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, design, statistics

I know this is a detail, but this kind of stuff bothers me once I notice it.

And I just noticed now that GIS SE makes some rather strange use of Title Case. When you are on a question page, you see some statistics in the right side bar; for example:

> [image: screenshot showing what this question is about]

As a non-native speaker of English, I have always found Title Case somewhat odd and distracting; but I can usually adjust to that, it's just some cultural thing / part of the language after all. Except when it's overused, such as here (IMHO):

- 2 **D**ays **A**go
- 32 **T**imes
- **T**oday

These are not even titles! Consider this post my vote for fixing the capitalization of these statistics, e.g. as follows:

- Asked: 2 **d**ays **a**go
- Viewed: 32 **t**imes
- Active: **t**oday

Comment: Have you seen the mishmash of case used for *actual questions*? The term itself doesn't even know if it should be capitalized (seriously, Google title case and see if you can find any pattern to when it is or isn't capitalized *within sentences*). There are also conflicting guidelines on when/how to use it, but the general consensus seems to be pick something and be consistent about it.

Answer (score 3):

This is both a CSS and HTML template issue. The recent updates to the site's CSS remove the initial caps on all of the words, but they also remove it from 'asked', 'viewed', and 'active' because those words aren't capitalized in the template. To be completely honest the inconsistency in capitalization on our sites drives me crazy, but that's another project for another time.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the fix for this may just flow through from the coming CSS update referred to at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3942 because I have noticed that title case is not used at two other sites that I frequent (which I know are already using it):

- [The association bonus should not enable users to vote on every site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183109/the-association-bonus-should-not-enable-users-to-vote-on-every-site)
- https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/what-is-the-meaning-of-bound-to-in-this-18th-century-us-virginia-will

I'm trying to confirm via the all mods chat room at the moment but that has been unexpectedly slow to respond so I have asked on Meta SE as well:

[Will CSS Update address Title Case in Question stats for sites not yet updated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256478/will-css-update-address-title-case-in-question-stats-for-sites-not-yet-updated)

Comment: Thank you for following this up!

Comment: @stakx I've just added a bounty to my Meta SE question - I'm surprised it is not yet answered so the question must be harder than I thought.